# Calculate GroupSummary Value programmatically in DevExpress

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

In my code; I calculate 3 `GroupSummary` value with `ASPxGridview`;

```
<dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="RISK_EUR" SummaryType="SUM" ShowInGroupFooterColumn="RISK_EUR" DisplayFormat="n0" />
<dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="IPOTEK" SummaryType="AVERAGE" ShowInGroupFooterColumn="IPOTEK" DisplayFormat="n0" />
<dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="MV_BERND" SummaryType="SUM" ShowInGroupFooterColumn="MV_BERND" DisplayFormat="n0" />
```

**When i grouping**, I want calculate another column's GroupSummary value like;

```
 GroupSummary[RISK_EUR] - GroupSummary[IPOTEK] - GroupSummary[MV_BERND]
```

How?

**NOTE**: I can't calculate this value calculating for every row and then total them, because this 3 GroupSummary's SummaryType isn't same. (One is AVERAGE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be implemented by using [custom summary](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3762).  When you adjust it, the grid will raise the [CustomSummaryCalculate](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_CustomSummaryCalculatetopic) event for every record in every group.  To distinguish between groups, the event arguments class provides the SummaryProcess property.  So, you should use this event handler to manually calculate GroupSummary[RISK_EUR], GroupSummary[IPOTEK] and GroupSummary[MV_BERND] values.  Using them, you will be able to calculate the resulting summary value.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give an example for this?

Comment: For example e.TotalValue["ColumnName"] Like this calculation is possible?

Comment: There is an example in the help topic for the CustomSummaryCalculate event.  Have you seen it?  If this does not help, please let me why.

Comment: I solve it with *e.GetGroupSummary(e.GroupRowHandle, grid.GroupSummary[i]));* Thank you very very very much !